# std::bind and winsock.h bind confusion

Tags: c++, namespaces, winsock, std

I'm working on a very large project and in one file we all of the sudden got a compile-time error where the compiler seems to think that our call to winsock.h `bind()` is actually a call to `std::bind()`. It seems that somewhere  in a include file there is `using namespace std` code snippet. We could try and find where these `using namespace std` are in use and remove them, but perhaps there is a better way to do this?

Comment: namespaces are fun aren't they?

Comment: Remove `using namespace std`, otherwise you will have the same problem sometime in the future with some other name.

Comment: @juanchopanza, In my project, I can't find where brings in `using namespace std`, because the project is large. And even if I find where brings in `using namespace std`, I doubt I can remove it easily.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can change your calls to use `::bind()` to specify the global namespace.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this is unfortunate. As I described at http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2011-03/msg00143.html the `std::bind` template is a better match unless you use exactly the  right argument types:

> The problem is that the socket bind() function has this signature:
>   `int bind(int, const sockaddr*, socklen_t);`
>   so the call in the example using a non-const pointer finds that the
>   variadic template std::bind is a better match.  The same would happen
>   if the third argument was any integral type except socklen_t.

Your code would work with GCC because I added a conforming extension to GCC's `std::bind` to prevent this ambiguity, by removing `std::bind` from the overload set if the first argument is "socket-like", which I defined using `is_integral` and `is_enum`.  That doesn't help with other implementations though.

Removing the `using namespace std;` is a good idea anyway, but may not be entirely sufficient, because an unqualified call to `bind()` that happens to use a type defined in namespace `std` (such as `std::size_t`) could still find `std::bind` by argument dependent lookup. Jonathan Potter's answer is the best way to ensure you get the right function: qualify it as `::bind`.